# Custom RPC Error on sp_api::decl_runtime_apis!

Tags: substrate-node, wasm, compilation

We are adding a custom rpc and following along with
https://github.com/AlexD10S/susbtrate-node-template/blob/rpc-custom-methods/pallets/template/rpc/runtime-api/src/lib.rs

and

https://github.com/valentinfernandez1/RPC-DeepDives

and it runs great building local.
however when i try to build wasm we get an error in the file runtime-api/src/lib.r

`` use of undeclared crate or module `std ``

```
pallets/template/rpc/runtime-api/src/lib.rs:5:1
   |
5  | / sp_api::decl_runtime_apis! {
6  | |     pub trait TemplateApi {
7  | |         fn sum_5() -> u32;
8  | |         fn sum_and_store(value: u32) -> u32;
9  | |     }
10 | | }
   | |_^ use of undeclared crate or module `std`
```

any ideas?

Comment: Could you send your current repo link?